# Calculating percentage in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this for example:

```
string adm
A       2
A       1
B       2
A       1
C       1
A       2
```

And through a SQL query I want something like this:

```
string    perc_adm (%)
A            50
B            100
C            0
```

I want the percentage of number 2 occurrence in each string. I am able to get this in separate conditions but I need just one condition with it. 
Also I have some divided by zero error. How do I correct that in the condition?

Comment: you do realise your percentage sums to 150% in your example. According to your case, if you should A,66.66% and B,33.33% .

Comment: Please, add your actual code to the question

Comment: Sorry, but my code is correct. I want the percentage of number 2 occurence in each string. There is 4 string A and two of them have number 2, so the percentage is 50%. There is one string B with value 2, so the occurence is 100%.

Comment: Ah, now the question is more clear. Than move this example from the comment to the question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try:

```
select 
    string,
    (cnt_2/total::float)*100 perc_adm
from (
    select 
        string, 
        count(*) total, 
        sum(case when adm = 2 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_2
    from tbl
    group by string
) x
order by string
```

Here `total::float` convert the division into a `float` value, else `int/int ==>int`.

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a7e4/9)

Comment: +1. Consider using [`nullif`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) to protect your division (in case `count(*)` returns no rows) : `cnt_2 / nullif(total, 0)::float`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select 
    string,
    100.0*sum(case when adm = 2 then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as perc_adm
from tbl
group by string
order by string
```

This way avoids subquery