# Calculating Percentages in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm completely new to PostgreSQL. I have the following table called my_table:

```
a    b    c        date
1    0    good     2019-05-02
0    1    good     2019-05-02
1    1    bad      2019-05-02
1    1    good     2019-05-02
1    0    bad      2019-05-01
0    1    good     2019-05-01
1    1    bad      2019-05-01
0    0    bad      2019-05-01
```

I want to calculate the percentage of 'good' from column c for each date. I know how to get the number of 'good':

```
SELECT COUNT(c), date FROM my_table WHERE c != 'bad' GROUP BY date;
```

That returns:

```
count    date
3        2019-05-02
1        2019-05-01
```

My goal is to get this:

```
date         perc_good
2019-05-02   25
2019-05-01   75
```

So I tried the following:

```
SELECT date, 
       (SELECT COUNT(c) 
        FROM my_table 
        WHERE c != 'bad' 
        GROUP BY date) / COUNT(c) * 100 as perc_good 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY date;
```

And I get an error saying

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.

I found this answer but not sure how to or if it applies to my case:

[Calculating percentage in PostgreSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413958/calculating-percentage-in-postgresql)

How do I go about calculating the percentage for multiple rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`avg()` is convenient for this purpose:

```
select date,
       avg( (c = 'good')::int ) * 100 as percent_good
from t
group by date
order by date;
```

How does this work?  `c = 'good'` is a boolean expression.  The `::int` converts it to a number, with 1 for true and 0 for false.  The average is then the average of a bunch of 1s and 0s -- and is the ratio of the true values.

Answer (score 3):

For this case you need to use conditional [`AVG()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT 
  date, 
  100 * avg(case when c = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) perc_good 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=5f99c03a29c85c967b092faf34cdc309).

Answer (score 1):

You could use  a conditional sum for get the good value and count for total

below an exaustive code sample

```
  select  date
    , count(c) total 
    , sum(case when c='good' then 1 else 0 end)  total_good
    , sum(case when c='bad' then 1 else 0 end)  total_bad 
    , (sum(case when c='good' then 1 else 0 end) / count(c))* 100 perc_good
    , (sum(case when c='bad' then 1 else 0 end) / count(c))* 100 perc_bad 
  from my_table
  group by  date
```

and for your result

```
  select  date
    , (sum(case when c='good' then 1 else 0 end) / count(c))* 100 perc_good
  from my_table
  group by  date
```

or as suggested  by a_horse_with_no_name using count(*) filter()

```
select  date
  , ((count(*) filter(where c='good'))/count(*))* 100 perc_good
from my_table
group by  date
```

Comment: In Postgres you can simplify the `CASE` expressions to e.g. `count(*) filter (where c = 'good')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  .. correct  .it is my habit to use CASE

Comment: @Abelisto: that still uses integer division, you will need `(...)::numeric / count(*)` to avoid that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes surely. But in integer arithmetic `x * 100 / y` usually more accurate then `x / y * 100` Actually in this answer result always will be `0`: `select 99 / 100 * 100, 99 * 100 / 100;`